# window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory(...).then is not a function

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I'm using [webchat-es5.js](https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/4.6.0/webchat-es5.js) and its throwing error like window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory(...).then is not a function. Need IE support also using es5.js.

```js
window.fetch('https://webchat-mockbot.azurewebsites.net/directline/token', { method: 'POST' })
    .then(function (res) {
      return res.json();    
    })
  .then(function (json) {
  const token = json.token;

  window.fetch('https://webchat-mockbot.azurewebsites.net/speechservices/token', { method: 'POST' })
    .then(function (res) {
    return res.json();
  })
    .then(function (json) {
    const region = json.region;
    const authorizationToken = json.token;

    window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory({ authorizationToken: authorizationToken , region: region })
      .then(function (webSpeechPonyfillFactory) {
      window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: token }),
        webSpeechPonyfillFactory: webSpeechPonyfillFactory
      }, document.getElementById('webchat'));

      document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @StevenKanberg its working for me Thanks.Upvoted already

Answer (score 0):

This is the setup that is working for me. I run a server locally to fetch the actual tokens. This way I don't need to include any secrets in the client.

```js
window.fetch( 'http://localhost:3500/directline/token', { method: 'POST' } )
    .then( function ( res ) {
      return res.json();
    } )
    .then( function ( res ) {
      let token = res.token;
      window.fetch( 'http://localhost:3500/speechservices/token', { method: 'POST' } )
        .then( function ( res ) {
          return res.json();
        } )
        .then( function ( res ) {
          let authorizationToken = res.authorizationToken;
          window.WebChat.renderWebChat( {
            directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine( {
              token: token,
              webSocket: true
            } ),
            webSpeechPonyfillFactory: window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory( {
              region: 'westus2',
              authorizationToken: authorizationToken
            } )
          }, document.getElementById( 'webchat' ) );
        });
    } );
```

Hope of help!